# Why this strange behaviour of ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream throwing EOFException?

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I wrote a custom serializing/de-serializing logic for persisting some of the data as Java default serialization turned out to be both time and memory expensive. For this purpose I wrote `readObject(ObjectInput in)` and `writeObject(ObjectOutput out)` methods for the class(es) that needs persisting. However I noticed that if I do not use any `out.writeObject(obj)` in `writeObject(ObjectOutput out)` method then it always throws `EOFException`.

Consider the following example:

**Data.java**

```
public class Data implements BaseData {

private String messageUID;
private String rawData;
private String data;
private Long type;
private Boolean processed = false;
private String processedMessage;
private String processedDetaildMessage;

// getter setter

public void readObject(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    messageUID = in.readUTF();
    rawData = in.readUTF();
    data = in.readUTF();
    type = in.readLong();
    processed = in.readBoolean();
    if (processed) {
        processedMessage = in.readUTF();
        processedDetaildMessage = in.readUTF();
    }
}

public void writeObject(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(messageUID);
    out.writeUTF(rawData);
    out.writeUTF(data);
    out.writeLong(type);
    out.writeBoolean(processed);
    if (processed) {
        out.writeUTF(processedMessage);
        String tempDetailsMessage[] = processedDetaildMessage.split(" more");
        out.writeUTF(tempDetailsMessage[tempDetailsMessage.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

However whenever I use above code the `out` stream is always missing some information at the end (from `processedDetaildMessage` field) and I get `EOFException` while reading it form `in`, stacktrace below (Data.java line 216 is `processedDetaildMessage = in.readUTF()`);

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2766)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFChar(ObjectInputStream.java:3158)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3055)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1072)
    at com.smartstream.common.Data.readObject(Data.java:216)
    at com.smartstream.common.PerformanceTest.getObjectFromBytes(PerformanceTest.java:168)
    at com.smartstream.common.PerformanceTest.access$0(PerformanceTest.java:160)
    at com.smartstream.common.PerformanceTest$1.mapRow(PerformanceTest.java:119)
    at com.smartstream.common.PerformanceTest$1.mapRow(PerformanceTest.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:676)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:731)
    at com.smartstream.common.PerformanceTest.readFromDb(PerformanceTest.java:109)
    at com.smartstream.common.PerformanceTest.main(PerformanceTest.java:66)
```

so I though I would put some extra byte/s of information at the end after writing all required fields and will not read them so that I don't reach end of file while reading. I tried all of these `out.writeByte(-1)`, `out.writeInt(-1)`, `out.writeLong(2342343l)`, `out.writeUTF("END_OF_STREAM")` but those make no difference. finally I did this `out.writeObject(new String("END_OF_STREAM"))` and it works fine. Can someone please explain as to why outputstream misses some information if none of the information is written using `writeObject()` method. Below is how I read and write to/from streams;

```
private byte[] getObjectAsBytes(Data data) {
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
    try {
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        // Use this for java default serialization
        // oos.writeObject(data);
        data.writeObject(oos);
        byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (oos != null) {
            try {
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return byteArray;
}

private Data getObjectFromBytes(byte[] byteArray) {
    Data data = new Data();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    try {
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        // Use this for java default serialization
        // data = (Data) ois.readObject();
        data.readObject(ois);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ois != null) {
            try {
                ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

If anyone is interested below is what is written in the streams;

**persisted data with original code (throws `EOFException` and missing information)** (don't confuse the stacktrace with original issue this stacktrace is persisted as field `processedDetailedMessage`)

```
¬í---z-------3507319347632941385----FEEDER-----1437052314954 ---This is a random string---N---þ%J---!this is message of processed dataÛ
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment TLM_DBO.SYS_LOB0000076335C00008$$ by 8192 in tablespace WIN_SL_TABLE
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePre
```

**persisted data after writing extra string at the end using `writeObject` method**

```
¬í---z-------3507319347632941385----FEEDER-----1437052314954 ---This is a random string---N---þ%J---!this is message of processed dataÛ
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01691: unable to extend lob segment TLM_DBO.SYS_LOB0000076335C00008$$ by 8192 in tablespace WIN_SL_TABLE
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePrz-----NeparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3550)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1374)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:975)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.execute(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:642)
at com.smartstream.control.engine.config.dao.jdbc.ProcessExecutionAuditDetailDao$1.doInPreparedStatement(ProcessExecutionAuditDetailDao.java:115)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:586)
... 23t 
END_OF_STREAM
```

*PS ---- represents unreadable bytes*

Comment: This is not an answer but a recommendation to have a look at java Externalizable as it is basically a cutom serialize-interface.
This might be a bit cleaner :)

Comment: @red13 thanks for recommendation but we can't use Externalizable because in the platform this code runs requires this class to be Serializable  and it throws exception as Externalizable is not supported by that platform. So the class is Serializable but reason behind writing custom logic is memory foot print and performance.

Comment: You don't need these `readObject()` or `writeObject()` methods. They don't do anything for you that default serialization wouldn't also do. I would delete them and use `Data data = (Data)ois.readObject();` instead of `data.readObject(ois);`, and `oos.writeObject(data);` instead of `data.writeObject(oos);`. And as you have it now, those methods are public, which is a security breach.

Comment: @EJP with all due respect you don't get the problem in the question. I already mentioned default serialization is memory and performance expensive. And the code snippet I've added in question is just minimal representation of the problem and not the actual code. In the actual code the class has much complex data types and java writes all of those fully qualified class names while serializing, which is completely unnecessary. In our actual code if java default serialization is used serialized class takes over 8000 bytes while using custom serializer we managed to do it under 3000 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your persisted data is incomplete because you are creating your byte array *before* flushing the ObjectOutputStream.  In `getObjectAsBytes(Data)` move `byteArray = bos.toByteArray();` after the finally block to make it work.  Alternatively, the method could be written more succinctly as follows (requires Java 7+):

```
private byte[] getObjectAsBytes(Data data) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
        data.writeObject(oos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

I tested both ways in my own program and they both prevent the EOFException from being thrown.

As far as why having a writeObject was working, that's because the [underlying writeObject implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0%28java.lang.Object%2Cboolean%29) toggles block data mode at the beginning and ending of the method, and [changing the block data mode performs a drain](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#ObjectOutputStream.BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode%28boolean%29) which writes all data to the underlying OutputStream, which for a ByteArrayOutputStream is effectively the same as a flush.

Comment: or just change 
    return byteArray; to 
  return bos.toByteArray();

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the actual reason for the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This issue is caused because of the different implementations of `writeObject` method and some other non-generic `write*` methods i.e. `writeUTF`. The writeObject method toggles to data block mode at the start and at the end of the method which results all the data being written to underlying `OutputStream`, this has same affect as calling flush on `outputStream`. This means that you cannot create another byteArray before flushing the remaining data to the stream. It would be best if you stick with `writeObject` method for now; ie

```
public void writeObject(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(messageUID);
    out.writeUTF(rawData);
    out.writeUTF(data);
    out.writeLong(type);
    out.writeBoolean(processed);
    if (processed) {
        out.writeUTF(processedMessage);
        String tempDetailsMessage[] = processedDetaildMessage.split(" more");
        out.writeObject(tempDetailsMessage[tempDetailsMessage.length - 1]);
    }
}
```